# How to change environment variable in .Net using Docker?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, docker-compose

I changed it in docker-compose.override.yml

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

and when it's `Development` everything works fine. However, when I change it to anything else ex. `Production` the containers have correct environment variable but localhost gets a 404 not found error.

Comment: Is the 404 on the Swagger endpoint? Swagger is only available in Development environment (by default).

Comment: The 404 is both on Swagger endpoint and core url which I set up in docker-compose.override.yml as well `ports:
      - "8080:80"`

Comment: what are you setting based on the env variable? this doesn't seem to be a docker env var issue but a .NET env var issue. please correct me if I'm wrong